# Microsoft Dynamics AX - Sales Order to Invoice class location

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm looking to make a modification in the logic where an invoice is made from a Sales Order.

In other words, as soon as the Sales Order status changes to "Invoiced", I want to be able to add some additional code there that updates something else.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding the class where this is performed. Can somebody point me in the right direction? It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes you are looking for are

- `\Classes\SalesFormLetter_Invoice` - For interacting with SalesEditLines
- `\Classes\SalesInvoiceJournalCreate` - Creating journal data
- `\Classes\SalesInvoiceJournalPost` - Posting a journal
- `\Classes\SalesInvoiceJournalPrint` - Printing
- `\Classes\SalesFormletterParmDataInvoice` - Creating parm data

**The specific method you probably want is** `\Classes\SalesInvoiceJournalPost\postJournalPost`, which is executed after the journal has posted from `\Classes\FormletterService\run#91`

Refer to this whitepaper for some more information:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272871.aspx